# No audio through speakers but headphones work fine

Tags: sound, 14.04, dell, pulseaudio, speakers

1I recently bought a Dell Latitude E7440 laptop. It came with Windows 7 preinstalled and eveything works fine with it. But I'm planning to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it and when I boot from a USB stick, I don't get any audio and the multitouch of the touch pad doesn't work. I have tried looking for drivers for them online and searched for people with similar issues, but I was unable to find a solution to the problem. I am doing all my experiments on the OS on the USB stick and plan to install it once I am certain of the solutions. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

**Edit 1:** I installed it on my laptop. I have audio output from my headphones but none through my speakers. I see the value set to **00** in `alsamixer` for `Speaker` but I am unable to change it. Also, I tried reinstalling `pulseaudio` using the commands available online and also adding the generic type to the end of the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. But nothing seems to work.

**Edit 2:** Okay this is crazy, but I read this suggestion [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2197749&p=12892736#post12892736) and it said close the lid and open it again. When I closed the lid Ubuntu went to sleep and then when I logged in again, the internal speakers started working. Also, the first time I installed Ubuntu, it was in dual boot with Windows 7. I somehow screwed up the MBR and reinstalled Ubuntu. When Windows was not detected, the sound from internal speakers was coming. When I repaired the MBR, the sound was gone. That's when I tried the lid trick. Any idea what's up?

Answer (score 3):

After launching **alsamixer** in a terminal:

- left/right arrows key to move around faders,
- up/down arrows to increase volume  (speaker in your case)
- "m" key to mute/unmute
- Press F6 to select another soundcard (modern pc often have one more soundcard for HDMI output, sometimes the main soundcard if the second one)

If you have no luck, try to run and share Alsa-info script as explained here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo

Comment: I did do that. I'll get you the output of the script.

Comment: I didn't run it yet, but check **Edit 2**

Comment: Wow your Edit 2 actually works. I'm super confused why it's like that...

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, I have a dual boot with windows 8.1.

When when my windows updated, I came back with windows and I had sound on microphones but nothing on speakers.

I did a lot of search and things like this answer but it didn't work.
Finally from some article and this post found out that my speakers are put to sleep by windows, 
1-restarted windows, 
2-came back with ubuntu and 
3- closed the lid and opened it, 
and it solved my problem !