# Cannot find sound settings menu in Ubuntu 14.04 after removing pulseaudio

Tags: sound, 14.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I cannot get any audio out of my speakers but the headphones work fine in Ubuntu 14.04. You can find my question about that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468109/). Therefore I followed the instructions online and removed and reinstalled `pulseaudio` and `alsa-base`. But now I cannot find my sound settings menu. I tried reinstalling them again, but it did not work. The headphones still work though. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

(Re?)Install the "unity-control-center" package (this depends on the libcanberra-pulse as well), i.e. run

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

in a terminal. This fixed it for me. :)